# Selenium xpath with round brackets

Tags: selenium, xpath

Dealing with Selenium + ExtJs-generated html is never a joy, especially when you have no way of changing the source. My current problem is in trying to click a button that is contained in the 4th parent of a form containing a particular label. No useful ids or class names are available.

Strangely (I guess its an extJs thing), the button is outside of the form, which is why the parent chain. There are multiple forms in the page as well. But no problem with xpath.

In Firefox Xpath checker, I can run this xpath - and it finds the button.

```
(//form[.//label[contains(text(),'Annual')]])[1]//parent::div//parent::div//parent::div//parent::div//button[.='Calculate']
```

When I tried it in Selenium RC, it stripped off the round brackets. I am monitoring Selenium log output so its obvious when this happens.  Another stackoverflow thread says when that happens to put xpath=  in front as Selenium does not know something that starts w/o // is an xpath. So...

```
xp = "xpath=(//form[.//label[contains(text(),'Annual')]])[1]//parent::div//parent::div//parent::div//parent::div//button[.='Calculate']"
result = self.selenium.click_at( xp )
```

The Selenium log shows the round brackets are now preserved, but the click is not executed - click_at() returns false and no error is generated.

What (no doubt deadly obvious thing) am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure about the double slashes? In xpath `//` is an abbreviation for `descendant-or-self::node()/` which is not even remotely the same as `/`! Therefore `//parent::div` looks quite strange to me...

Comment: Your are right -it is broken that way. But even updated Selenium cannot seem to deal with the (bracketed) expression. Worked around this by first extracting an id from the form and building on that without round braces.

Comment: Can you show the HTML that xpath looks very convoluted...

Comment: It would run many hundreds of lines of ext-generated html nested up to 30 levels deep to show what I am up against. I can put up a contrived example if you want.

Comment: I'm actually thinking that you can do away with a lot of what it there but with no idea of what the HTML looks like I can't really give you an accurate answer.

Also keying your XPath of something that is not an ID means that it's going to scan through the entire DOM every time which is never great from a perfomance point of view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [xpath parentheses selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15905126/xpath-parentheses-selenium)