# xpath parentheses selenium

Tags: xpath, selenium, selenium-ide, parentheses

I want to select the second match of my path in a document in selenium IDE:
This is the path. I am sure it is valid because Firebug can find it with no problems

```
(//label[text() = "stupid"])[2]
```

Selenium does not think this is an element. I don't even think it recognizes it as a valid path.

```
[error] locator not found: (//label[text() = "stupid"])[2]
```

Comment: also, how do I get markdown to not treat // as a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the "xpath=" label if the locator is not starting with "//". Yours is starting with "(" so:

```
xpath=(//label[text() = "stupid"])[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, selenium needs to be told that the locator is an Xpath.

this can be accomplished by appending (with no whitespace)`"xpath="`to the head of the locator.

Comment: Please put the version of Selenium you are using next time. The old RC API only applies to this.

Comment: @Arran The Q is tagged "selenium-ide", so it's not WebDriver.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text() = 'stupid'])[2]"));
```

remember in Java " "(parenthesis) , needs to be escaped or replace it either using ' ' or \"

Comment: The question is about Selenese, not Java.